# Do WSDL targetNamespace and XML Schema targetNamespace have to be the same?

Tags: namespaces, wsdl, xsd

In a WSDL file the global WSDL targetNamespace seems to usually be the same as the targetNamespace for the  XML Schema. Does this have to be this way? Or would it work equally well if I defined a different targetNamespace for the XML Schema as for the WSDL file?

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly have different namespaces for the WSDL and the Schema specifications... for example you can have:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://soa.jboss.org/CommonService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://service.foo.com/" version="1.0"> ...
```

So you have the targetNamespace *http://soa.jboss.org/CommonService* for the WSDL and  you have *http://service.foo.com/* in the schema...

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://service.foo.com/" version="1.0">...
```